# How to print n amount of characters before next line?

Tags: c

I have to print out the binary values of a file along with the offset and characters in columns with each other. However, for the characters, I am having issues printing out all the values. I believe the issue lies with the way the program checks to see if i counter is a multiple of 10 and only prints the characters when that happens so when the i is less than ten and less than ten characters are left it doesnt print them. I am not sure though. I would like some assistance rectifying this issue. I need a new line printed out in the character portion every ten characters and it must not interfere with the rest of the information being printed out.
[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3hVH.png)

```
int main()
{
   char file_info[250]="I like pineapples!";
   FILE *fptr;
   if ((fptr = fopen("try.bin","wb")) == NULL){
       printf("Error! opening file");
       exit(1);
   }

      fwrite(&file_info, sizeof(char), 250, fptr);

   fclose(fptr);
fptr=fopen("try.bin","rb");
 char file_array[250];

fread(file_array,sizeof(char),250,fptr); // read one character

int i=0,num=0,j=0,count=0;
printf("Offset               Bytes             Characters\n");
printf("------  -----------------------------  ----------");
 for(i=0;i<strlen(file_array);i++){

     if(i%10==0)
        {
            if(i>=9){
            count=j;
            printf("  ");
            for(;j<count+10;j++)
            {
                printf("%c",file_info[j]);
            }
            }
            printf("\n %5d ",num*10);
            num++;

        }


 printf(" %x",file_array[i]);
 }
 fclose(fptr);

 return 0;
}
```

I expect the output for the characters column to show the entire sentence "I like pineapples!" but the actual output is "I like pin" which are the first 10 characters and the rest characters that do not add up to 10 are left out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the optimal way. But this one will work:

```
char file_info[250] = "I like pineapples!";
char file_array[250] = "I like pineapples!";

int i = 0, num = 0, j = 0, count = 0;

printf("Offset               Bytes             Characters\n");
printf("------  -----------------------------  ----------");

while (i < strlen(file_array)) {
  printf("\n %5d ", num*10);
  num++;
  int maxOffset = count + 10;
  for (int x = count; x < maxOffset; x++) {
    printf(" %02x", file_array[x]);
    if (x + 1 == maxOffset) printf("  ");
  }
  for (int x = count; x < maxOffset; x++) {
    printf("%c", file_info[x]);
  }
  count = i = i + 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are always checking **if(i%10==0)** but your's string length is 18. 
It's mean **printf("%c",file_info[j])** can't run when **i > 10**.

Comment: actually printf("%c",file_info[j]) does run when i >10 (eg.20 ) as long as that i is a multiple of 10 since i%10==0 checks for multiples of 10

Comment: Yes. I know but in this case, your string length is 18. 
Your **for loop** will break when **i = 17**.

Comment: um i dont understand what you mean exactly. can you propose a solution for the issue?